# C# parallel.for loop fully uses cores of CPU1 but not CPU2

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.for

A C# method that uses parallel.for fully uses all cores in a 10-core cpu (on a dual Xeon 64GB RAM windows 10 workstation), but does not use any of the other available 10 physical cores on the second cpu.  Even though the process' affinity (in Task Manager) indicates all cores are available to it.  Any thoughts / approaches to get the process to use all available cores?  I do see a massive performance improvement going from standard coding to parallel.for in this instance; it seems a pity to give up another 100% improvement in speed.  Thanks.

IMPORTANT OBSERVATION:  Looking in Task Manager, it's apparent that the cores the process does use are distributed across both Xeon CPUs.  IOW, it uses about half the cores of each CPU.

ADDITIONAL INFO:  Environment.ProcessorCount = 32.  Even though the system has 20 physical cores, and thus 40 logical cores.  And clearly the process does NOT use all these 32 cores.  It uses at most 20.  FWIW, on a single core i7-3770 the process works as expected, using close to 100% of the 8 logical cores available.

ADDITIONAL 2:  The configuration changes suggested by Luaan did not affect the number of available processors:  still 32.

ADDITIONAL 3: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Comment: How many cores have you specified in msconfig.exe ?

Comment: Are those CPUs on NUMA? Are they in the same processor group? Does .NET have access to both if there are multiple? Check `Environment.ProcessorCount`, that's what `Parallel.For` uses to determine the amount of workers to create. If you manually create additional threads, do these also saturate the second CPU?

Comment: How are you doing all your processing? my nasty hack file finder seems to use all cores available to it it uses a combination of tasks and paralell fors

Comment: BTW you would never get another 100% improvement, data needs to be copied over to those individual cores' cache.

Comment: Check your bios if there is an advanced setting to assign each socket an extra processor group. HP servers are known for this to enable it by default.

Comment: Which Windows 10 version are You using? There are limits for some editions. Unfortunately I have not found a definitive source for that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to guess here - your two CPUs are in two different processor groups. By default, .NET only uses one processor group.

The minimal configuration required to expand this support is this:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true"/>
      <GCCpuGroup enabled="true"/>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

See [Thread_UseAllCpuGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj665638(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Processor Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503(v=vs.85).aspx) for reference.

This is also described in the MSDN docs for [Environment.ProcessorCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the current machine contains multiple processor groups, this property returns the number of logical processors that are available for use by the common language runtime (CLR).

Comment: Is this the "official" way of doing this? Seems like a bit of a work around for something that should happen in my opinion by default anyway.

Comment: @user9993 Have you ever worked with multi-CPU systems? They're even more tricky than simple multi-threaded systems. You wouldn't want to get random exceptions "by default" just because you ran a desktop .NET application on a multi-CPU system, would you? The defaults are always the *safest* option, not necessarily the most performant. Not to mention that having the GC span multiple CPUs (especially on NUMA) is extra tricky. Most applications don't know how to deal with systems like that, because you don't encouter them on desktop systems.